# Как Telegram боту узнать новых пользователей, которые добавляются в чат? - C#

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram

Пишу бота для администрирования чата. Подскажите, как боту узнать новых пользователей, которые добавляются в чат? Как это реализовать?

Comment: Решения не знаю, к сожалению, но могу дать совет, как увеличить шансы на ответ. Советую не сужать вопрос до решения на c#. Уберите этот тег и спросите актуальный алгоритм. Спросите есть ли способ мгновенно узнать о добавлении нового пользователя в чат.

Comment: Если такого способа нет, то вам придётся самому с интервалом проверять чат на изменения количества пользователей, например, с помощью этого метода https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmemberscount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это делается очень просто - у объекта [Message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) есть поле **new_chat_member** типа [User](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user), соответственно при получении апдейтов проверяйте объект **Message** на наличие непустого поля **new_chat_member**, это и будет означать, что в чат добавлен новый юзер.

**Пример**:

```
 if (update.Type == UpdateType.MessageUpdate && update.Message.NewChatMember != null)
    {
       await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(update.Message.Chat.Id, $"*{update.Message.NewChatMember.FirstName}, добро пожаловать!*", true, false, 0, null, ParseMode.Markdown);
       return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Храните где-нибудь пользователей, если человек заходит - смотрите, есть ли он в списке, если нет - он новый. После того как этот случай обработаете - добавьте и его в список. По конкретной реализации не скажу, не пользовался `telegram-api`. Но не вижу тут ничего сложного.